# calculating no of users at each place

Tags: mysql

I have a table place which will store details about place like

`Place(id,name,detail,type,Pid);//pid is parent place id`

`User(id,name,detail);`

`user_place(uid,pid);//primary key of user and place table`

Here A place can be area,city,state or country.

I want to track no of users for perticular place

like for area I want to fetch total users of area i.e. 400

again for city I want to fetch total user(that will be total user of all area of city) i.e 50000(for city).

Similar for state and country.

for calculation above data, Is place table structure is correct? or any modification is required?
How to calculate no of users according to city,state,country?

Comment: `count` and `group by` type .

Comment: .. and a lot of `joins` since you're going hierarchical with your `places`

Comment: How can you fetch users based on area, city, state if there are no columns for that in `Place`?

Comment: I dont Know. 1 thing I asked is that is table structure is correct any modification required.

Comment: Is the Hierarchy consistent? i.e. Does "type" of city always have "state" as parent? If so this should be easy and I'll write a full answer.

Comment: Yes we will maintain hierarchy.

Comment: @Eterm is table structure is correct or any modification required

Comment: @vivekpansara obviously, `place` has a `type` which indicates if it is a `city`, `state`, `area`, `country`.

Comment: @xrcwrn what is the hierarchy? country ->  state -> city -> area?

Comment: @ country is top and area is lower level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions: a `user` is in an `area`. an `area` is in a `city`, a `city` is in a `country`.

total number of users in area `Arkham`:

```
select count(up.uid)
  from place p
    inner join user_place up
      on p.id = up.pid
  where p.type = 'Area' and p.name = 'Arkham';
```

Total number of users in the city `gotham`, which has multiple areas.

```
select count(up.uid)
  from place p
    inner join place p2
      on p.pid = p2.id and p.type = 'Area' and p2.type = 'City'
    inner join user_place up
      on p.id = up.pid
    where p2.name = 'gotham'
```

There is a demo of this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14238/5